# Matplotlib canvas as numpy array artefacts

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to convert a matplotlib figure into a numpy array. I have been able to do this by accessing the contents of the renderer directly. However, when I call imshow on the numpy array it has what looks like aliasing artefacts along the edges which aren't present in the original figure.

I've tried playing around with various parameters but can't figure out how to fix the artefacts from imshow. The differences in the images remain if I save the figures to an image file.

Note that what I want to achieve is a way to confirm that the content of the array is the same as the figure I viewed before. I think probably these artefacts are not present in the numpy array but are created during the imshow call. Perhaps approriate configuration of imshow can resolve the problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import math

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, angle=45, color="red"))
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.axis("off")
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.savefig("rec1.png")
plt.show()
X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(X)
plt.savefig("rec2.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `plt.imshow(X, interpolation='bicubic')` removes the aliasing but add a drop shadow

Comment: Could this be an issue with the python version you are using or with how your system is set up? If I just copypaste your example code, the original rectangle and the imshow rectangle look identical at the default resolution (no artifacts whatsover) and only get fuzzy when I zoom in extremely far (corner of the rectangle taking up the full, fullHD screen). I'm on (both rather old) fedora 27 with `2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
`

Comment: I would have thought that the biggest differences would be due to the backend being used, not the matplotlib version. Other @Paul: have you tried this with different backends?  Other factors that I would consider/investigate are DPI and figure size, possibly screen resolution.

Comment: @JC_CL you're probably on an old matplotlib version. They had `interpolation="bilinear"` by default for `imshow` before version 2 (or fedora maintainers kept the default for retrocompatibility or you have it on your `matplotlibrc`). The current default (`interpolation="nearest"`) shows the issue

Comment: @bobrobbob what looks like drop shadow might actually be some bug with alpha compositing or something wrong going on with alpha interpolation, if you do `imshow(X[..., :3], interpolation="bilinear")` it looks fine

Answer (score 1):

These are clearly resampling artefacts, which can be avoided by using [`plt.figimage`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figimage.html) which specifically adds a non-resampled image to the figure.

```
plt.figimage(X)
plt.show()
```

Note that this will not work with the `%matplotlib inline` in Jupyter Notebook, but it does work fine with `%matplotlib notebook` and with GUI backends.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the fig.tight_layout with padding of -1.08, I was able to get the exact image as the real image.

```
X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(X)
fig.tight_layout(pad=-1.08)
plt.savefig("rec2.png")
plt.show()
```

[Real Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpjFT.png)

[From numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA6Ro.png)

I hope that solves your problem, atleast till you find a better way. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The best one I can think of is by using cv2 (openCV-python) library. My solution does require saving the image and in the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in **B G R** order.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import math
import cv2 #import openCV

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0,0), 1, 1, angle=45, color="red"))
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_aspect(1)
plt.axis("off")
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.savefig("rec1.png")
plt.show()`

im = cv2.imread("rec1.png")
print(type(im)) #prints numpy.ndarray

cv2.imshow("pic",im) #creates a window named pic, loads im
cv2.waitKey(0) #has no time limit, window destroyed on any key press
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Final result looks like

[image: result]

Since it is a numpy array, you can call methods on it for your comparison.

```
print(im.shape) #prints (288, 432, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The image that is shown in the second plot is plotted smaller than the first image; the reason is that the complete first figure's image is squeezed into a newly created smaller axes -- this would be obvious when not turning the axes off.

In order to make sure the second figure only shows the image itself, you may adjust the margins, such that there is no spacing between the figure edge and the axes, using `subplots_adjust`.

```
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
fig.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(X)
```

This produces the desired plot.

Note however that the array is not exactly the same due to antialiasing being applied when saving the png file. You may find out via

```
X = np.array(fig.canvas.renderer._renderer)/255.
Y = plt.imread("rec1.png")
print(np.all(X==Y))  
## This prints False
```

Inversely speaking, if you want to have the same numpy array as the one that is saved, you should make sure to **use** the saved image itself.

```
plt.savefig("rec1.png")
X = plt.imread("rec1.png")
# use X from here onwards
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to the comments who pointed out interpolation as the cause. I found the following code (adapted for Python 3) which displays the image in the way I want; identical to the first image but via the numpy array.

```
import PIL.Image
from io import BytesIO
import IPython.display
import numpy as np
def showarray(a, fmt='png'):
    a = np.uint8(a)
    f = BytesIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

source: https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/2f1b9a255993bf9b2629

Comment: Will accept this as answer if no better answer comes up soon (e.g. using matplotlib)